# c++ error: call to non-static member function without an object argument

Tags: c++, adapter, clang

I inherited some code that uses the class adapter pattern and I want to convert it to use the object adapter pattern.

The custom class `string` is adapting `std::string`, and it's in the `MyString` namespace.
Here's  a snippet of how the code looks before I alter it.

```
// mystring.h
namespace MyString
{

// StringInterface is the new (abstract) interface that the client will use.
// Inheriting the implementation of std::string to build on top of it.
class string : public StringInterface, private std::string
{
  ...
};

}
```

---

```
// mystring.cpp
namespace MyString
{

...

string& MyString::string::operator=(const string& s) // copy assignment operator
{
  if (this != &s) std::string::operator=(s);
  return *this;
}

...

}
```

Once I remove the private inheritance of `std::string` (which I do because--correct me if I'm wrong--the object adapter pattern uses composition and not inheritance of the implementation), the statement `std::string::operator=(s);` causes the error "**call to non-static member function without an object argument**".

So I'm not really sure how to accomplish this. It's my first time dealing with the adapter pattern (and C++ isn't my strongest language); maybe I'm overlooking something simple.

Comment: Just assign `s` to your data member. No need to do the address check, either. Use the copy-swap idiom.

Comment: Don't inherit from things that don't have a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Rapptz, It was more or less fine - private inheritance - but they're trying to use composition instead now.

Comment: @chris swap was raising new compilation errors, and while debugging them I also tried Garcia's answer which also solves the problem.

Comment: @Dennis, Except copy-swap will never leave you with a (half-ass)igned object. Just `std::swap` each member.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using private inheritance to implement composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming you have made the `std::string` a member of your class

```
class string : public StringInterface
{
   ...
   std::string m_str;
   ...
};
```

you should then modify all your operations on the once "inherited" (but it's privately... well) `std::string` to your now member `std::string`, which in my example, is `m_str`. For example, instead of doing `std::string::size()`, you should do `m_str.size()`.

For your `operator=()`, you should then do it this way:

```
string& MyString::string::operator=(const string& s) // copy assignment operator
{
  if (this == &s) return *this;  // So you'll only have to do this test once

  m_str = s.m_str; // instead of std::string::operator=(s);
  // ...

  return *this;
}
```